# is expo the windows version of CocoaPods?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npx

Okay so what brings this up is the different installation procedures you have to do when installing dependencies in react native. Where I am confused most is making sure the installation is successful and all the file modification/linking went well.

I constantly see some dependencies telling me to do things in xcode while others require something of expo or a npx install. I guess this is a little late to be asking considering I have already installed so many things into my project but if I am using expo on a windows machine, can I ignore anything that I see using npx? I understand modifications requirede in expo need to be done but for an example like [this](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/installation.md)

Is the npm install command enough? To run on IOS that is.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to ignore a Mac if your development is for iOS. There is still built and compilation to be done in expo read here, https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/app-stores/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I‘m not sure I understood the question but I think what you are asking is if expo install replaces all npx install commands.

In that case, yes and no. Expo manages a lot in the installation process of dependencies, even some that require some native code. But just not all of them. Not all native modules can be installed by Expo (Even though there‘s a ton of them already)

But if you somehow need to install a native module, that is not yet covered by Expo, you can look into EAS, which allows native installations in an expo project.

Here‘s a link to their documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/